# Do DynamoDB update expressions allow condition expressions to target specific components of an update expressions?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have an item where multiple attributes may need to be updated (but not always), and each of them requires a different set of conditions. In the below example, I would like to do the following:

- Set a new `JobTitle` if it has changed, *and* the `LastUpdated` value is more recent
- Append a `Project ID` to the `ProjectsList` list and `Project` to `Projects` if a new `Project ID` listed.

Is it possible to run all of these updates within a single `update_item` expression, or is it necessary to use transactions?

#### Example item:

```py
{
    'PK': 'PERSON#123456789',
    'SK': 'PERSON#123456789',
    'ID': '123456789',
    'Name': 'Bob Smith',
    'Birthday': '01/01/2000',
    'Street': '65 LEXINGTON AVE',
    'Zip': '12345',
    'City': 'NEW YORK',
    'State': 'NY',
    'JobTitle': 'Project Manager',
    'LastUpdated': '20210101',
    'Projects': [
        {
            'Name': 'Project A',
            'ID': '987654321'
        },
        {
            'Name': 'Project B',
            'ID': '756394733'
        },
    ],
    "ProjectList": ['987654321', '756394733']
}
```

#### Each separate update expressions (via a `Table` resource):

```py
# Update job title if changed
r = table.update_item(
    Key = {
        "PK": data['PK'],
        "SK": data['SK']
    },
    UpdateExpression = "SET #JobTitle = :JobTitle",
    ExpressionAttributeNames = {
        "#JobTitle": "JobTitle",
        "#LastUpdated": "LastUpdated"
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues = {
        ":JobTitle": "Senior Project Manager",
        ":LastUpdated": '20210102'
    },
    ConditionExpression = "#LastUpdated < :LastUpdated AND #JobTitle <> :JobTitle"
)

# Update projects if not in list
r = table.update_item(
    Key = {
        "PK": data['PK'],
        "SK": data['SK']
    },
    UpdateExpression = """
        SET #Projects = list_append(if_not_exists(#Projects, :empty_list), :ProjectMap),
            #ProjectList = list_append(if_not_exists(#ProjectList, :empty_list), :ProjectID)
    """,
    ConditionExpression = "not(contains(#ProjectList, :ProjectID))",
    ExpressionAttributeNames = {
        "#Projects": "Projects",
        "#ProjectList": "ProjectList"
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues = {
        ":empty_list": [],
        ":ProjectMap": [{
            "Name": "Project C"
            "ID": "7463848373"
        }],
        ":ProjectID": ["7463848373"]
    }
)
```

#### What I want to do

```py
# (1) Update job title if changed or (2) update projects if not in list
r = table.update_item(
    Key = {
        "PK": data['PK'],
        "SK": data['SK']
    },
    UpdateExpression = """
        SET 
            #JobTitle = :JobTitle,
            #Projects = list_append(if_not_exists(#Projects, :empty_list), :ProjectMap),
            #ProjectList = list_append(if_not_exists(#ProjectList, :empty_list), :ProjectID)
    """,
    ExpressionAttributeNames = {
        "#JobTitle": "JobTitle",
        "#LastUpdated": "LastUpdated",
        "#Projects": "Projects",
        "#ProjectList": "ProjectList"
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues = {
        ":empty_list": [],
        ":JobTitle": "Senior Project Manager",
        ":LastUpdated": '20210102'
        ":ProjectMap": [{
            "Name": "Project C"
            "ID": "7463848373"
        }],
        ":ProjectID": ["7463848373"]
    },
    ConditionExpression = "(#LastUpdated < :LastUpdated AND #JobTitle <> :JobTitle) OR not(contains(#ProjectList, :ProjectID))"
)
```

I'm skeptical that this is possible due to this line in the AWS documentation:

*For these data manipulation operations, you can specify a condition expression to determine which items should be modified. **If the condition expression evaluates to true, the operation succeeds; otherwise, the operation fails.***

Comment: With the last ConditionExpression you basically say if this or this is true then do the update. You can have a case where the first condition is true and the second isn't (or the opposite). Do you want something like that?
Even if the answer is yes i would still keep them seperated operations because its cleaner, more readable and easier to debug.

Comment: I think I would need something different since I only want the updates with true conditions to run, rather than all of the updates in a case or alternative logic. I do agree that it's cleaner to break them out and add less complexity... seems like the way forward for now.